# Does placing an httpd server in front of a Vert.x application defeats Vert.x's purpose?

Tags: architecture, multithreading, apache, asynchronous

I'm watching a talk on Vert.x (not in English) and they say that "the whole architecture needs to be asynchronous from beginning to end", and cites as an example of what not to do putting an Apache httpd server in front of the Vert.x application, then explains that using Nginx would be a better idea.

I understand that Nginx follows an event-driven, asynchronous, single-threaded architecture like Vert.x, as opposed to Apache’s synchronous, one-thread-per-process model, but I don't see how that is a problem that affects the Vert.x application behind it.

Httpd will create a thread per request and forward that request to Vert.x. They're independent, and as long as httpd can keep up with the incoming traffic, how is it internal workings a problem?

Comment: His point is probably that httpd **can't** keep up with the incoming traffic as well as Vert.x can, so if you use httpd you're slowing down your application so much that you may as well not use Vert.x.

Answer (score 2):

The C10K problem is the issue:

> Apache creates processes and threads to handle additional connections. The administrator can configure the server to control the maximum number of allowable processes. This configuration varies depending on the available memory on the machine. Too many processes exhaust memory and can cause the machine to swap memory to disk, severely degrading performance. Plus, when the limit of processes is reached, Apache refuses additional connections.
>
> The limiting factor in tuning Apache is memory and the potential to dead-locked threads that are contending for the same CPU and memory. If a thread is stopped, the user waits for the web page to appear, until the process makes it free, so it can send back the page. If a thread is deadlocked, it does not know how to restart, thus remaining stuck.
>
> Nginx does not create new processes for each web request, instead the administrator configures how many worker processes to create for the main Nginx process. (One rule of thumb is to have one worker process for each CPU.) Each of these processes is single-threaded. Each worker can handle thousands of concurrent connections. It does this asynchronously with one thread, rather than using multi-threaded programming.

Distinguishing between performance and scalability is the key:

> The Apache problem is the more connections the worse the performance.
>
> Key insight: performance and scalability are orthogonal concepts. They don't mean the same thing. When people talk about scale they often are talking about performance, but there’s a difference between scale and performance. As we'll see with Apache.
>
> With short term connections that last a few seconds, say a quick transaction, if you are executing a 1000 TPS then you’ll only have about a 1000 concurrent connections to the server.
>
> Change the length of the transactions to 10 seconds, now at 1000 TPS you’ll have 10K connections open. Apache’s performance drops off a cliff though which opens you to DoS attacks. Just do a lot of downloads and Apache falls over.
>
> If you are handling 5,000 connections per second and you want to handle 10K, what do you do? Let’s say you upgrade hardware and double it the processor speed. What happens? You get double the performance but you don’t get double the scale. The scale may only go to 6K connections per second. Same thing happens if you keep on doubling. 16x the performance is great but you still haven’t got to 10K connections. Performance is not the same as scalability.
>
> The problem was Apache would fork a CGI process and then kill it. This didn’t scale.
>
> Why? Servers could not handle 10K concurrent connections because of O(n^2) algorithms used in the kernel.
>
> Two basic problems in the kernel:
>
> Connection = thread/process. As a packet came in it would walk down all 10K processes in the kernel to figure out which thread should handle the packet
>
> Connections = select/poll (single thread). Same scalability problem. Each packet had to walk a list of sockets.
>
> Solution: fix the kernel to make lookups in constant time
>
> Threads now constant time context switch regardless of number of threads.
>
> Came with a new scalable epoll()/IOCompletionPort constant time socket lookup.
>
> Thread scheduling still didn't scale so servers scaled using epoll with sockets which led to the asynchronous programming model embodied in Node and Nginx. This shifted software to a different performance graph.  Even with a slower server when you add more connections the performance doesn't drop off a cliff. At 10K connections a laptop is even faster than a 16 core server.

**References**

- [The Secret to 10 Million Concurrent Connections -The Kernel is the Problem, Not the Solution - High Scalability -](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html)
- [Nginx vs Apache - Anturis Blog](https://anturis.com/blog/nginx-vs-apache/)
- [Apache is Still the Best General-Purpose Web Server](https://blog.sourcerer.io/apache-is-still-the-best-general-purpose-web-server-dacedbd86921)
- [Comparing API Gateway Performances: NGINX vs. ZUUL vs. Spring Cloud Gateway vs. Linkerd](https://engineering.opsgenie.com/comparing-api-gateway-performances-nginx-vs-zuul-vs-spring-cloud-gateway-vs-linkerd-b2cc59c65369)
- [Optimizing Passenger + Nginx - Passenger Library](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/optimization/)
- [Optimizing Passenger + Apache - Passenger Library](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/optimization/)
- [A Framework for Verifying Scalability and Performance of Cloud Based Web Applications (pdf)](http://kodu.ut.ee/%7Esrirama/publications/theses/Framework4ScalabilitynPerformanceofCloudBasedWebApps_Vasar.pdf)